# method that takes an input String named word, and that swaps 2 characters in word that aren't at the beginning or end

Tags: methods, character

a method that takes an input String named word, and that swaps 2 characters in word that aren't at the beginning or end if word is more than 3 characters long, and then returns the modified word.  If word is length 3 or less, it should just return word.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you specify the language you're using? Have you tried anything yet? This looks like a problem that could be solved in most programming languages with a bit of research.

Comment: I  am using java and nope have not tried anything @JakobRunge

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your question looks kind of like homework to me, so instead of giving a full solution I'll provide some hints as to where you may find help:

1. Have a look at the [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world#Java) Hello World example to get going with a basic structure of your program.
2. Find out how to add a method to your first class, and how to specify its parameter and return values.
3. Use the strings [length](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_length#Java) method to distinguish the length of the input parameter for your method. Here it will also be helpful to have a look at basic control structures in Java `if(){}` is your friend!
4. Manipulate the String iff necessary and return the result.

If you encounter a concrete example feel welcome to search the web and ask further questions. However: please note that StackOverflow is not intended as a code writing service.